# How can I add an 'enhancement' sound filter in win7?

Tags: windows, windows-7, audio, core-audio

In windows 7, if one right clicks on the speaker icon in the taskbar, clicks playback devices, opens properties for one of the devices tab, then clicks the enhancements tab, one gets a list of filters ("Bass Boost" etc) that can be applied to that sound device. How can I register my own custom filter here?

Please note that I am not an IHV - horrible hacks involving unsigned drivers, etc are acceptable, as this will be primarily for my own use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're an audio IHV you register them with your INF.  The reference pages for them can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb981490.aspx).

Please note that to be used with Windows, sAPOs must be signed, otherwise they won't load into the audio engine.  To get your sAPO signed, you need to follow the WHQL signing requirements.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not an IHV - I'm trying to workaround the fact that the gain on one particular audio device I have is way too damn high (high as in, set the master volume to 5% and the application volume to 1% and it's just barely not high enough to cause ear damage). I'm open to horrible hacks if need be to inject a filter - this is purely for my own use :)

Comment: Then you're kinda stuck unfortunately.

What is this device that has such a broken volume control?

Comment: @Larry: jWINin JBM55 headphones. :/

Answer (score 1):

With USB headphones, how to you know the problem is on the windows side?  Maybe the electronics in the headphones is bad?  So I'll suggest soldering a resistor into the analog side of the headphone cable (i.e., hacking it old-school).

Comment: Setting the hardware volume control to zero under Linux is still quite loud - so I'm pretty sure it's actually the hardware mixer. That's why I want to knock down the magnitude of the samples before they get to the headphones. I'd rather not hack hardware, as it's not entirely obvious how to disassemble it without destroying it (no obvious screws etc) and I don't really know my way around hacking electronics...

Answer (score 0):

I notice that the device in question has an inline volume control.  Can you just turn it down from there to get it to an acceptable volume?

I doubt, given that you see a similar problem under Linux, your proposed solution would give the desired result even if you could get it working.

Comment: The inline volume control is just a HID device that triggers a volume mixer change on the computer side. :/