# How are "audio enchanments" in Windows 7 created?

Tags: audio, windows-7, drivers

If you go into Sounds->Playback Devices->(some audio card)->Configure->Enhancements on Windows 7, you can see a list of possible audio enhancements to choose from. I want to know, how are these enhancements created? What API does one use to get enhancements listed, etc?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1475074/how-can-i-add-an-enhancement-sound-filter-in-win7